# How does ListView save items data?

Tags: flutter

Let I have a StatefulWidget with

```
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => TextField(),
  itemCount: _count,
)
```

inside. When I do

```
setState(() {
  _count += 1;
});
```

the ListView rebuilds, but all data entered in text fields is kept. [Complete example](https://gist.github.com/PiN73/ab160fdc8a9d726c92af8d975a53c0bc)

How does it work? How do I achieve such behavior in custom widgets?

Comment: You can use `Key` in your custom widget and it should be saving data on its own when rebuilding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextField` creates default `TextEditingController` for itself, if no controller was assigned to it initially.

Also, [`didUpdateWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html) method is used to maintain & update `TextField`'s `State`. On rebuild `TextField` reuses the value from its previous `TextEditingController`.

I assume that is the method you are looking for, as it gets called whenever a parent widget rebuilds and requests its subtree to present new states.

For instance, this is how [`didUpdateWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html) is used by `TextField`:

```dart
@override
void didUpdateWidget(TextField oldWidget) {
  super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);

  if (widget.controller == null && oldWidget.controller != null)
    _controller = TextEditingController.fromValue(oldWidget.controller.value);
  else if (widget.controller != null && oldWidget.controller == null)
    _controller = null;

  // ...
}
```